# Listing all authorized services for given user in ArcGIS API for FLEX

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-flex-api

I'm trying to get the list of all authorized services for a given user in ArcGIS 10.1 API for FLEX.
I can't find a way to automatically list all of the services granted to my account.

I can fix the services in the configuration file but I need to get them automatically in case of any authorizations modifications made by the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Flex API that does that sort of metadata queries.  You would have to make your own http request (using the Apache/Adobe Flex SDK) and parse the response to get that list.  You can get the data back as xml using http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/?f=sitemap.